# React how can I render out the proper view based on condition?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

I have a component that renders out the proper view based on a search button. Right now it works, but I also wanted to display to screen a message if the user being searched for is not found.  I would ideally like to render out  component if my components state is null and "sorry user not found" if a search fails.

At the moment I am using

```
let allOrNo = this.props.view;
let renderMe;
 if(allOrNo === 'true') {
             renderMe= renderData;
 } else {
             renderMe = renderUser;
 }

return (
        <div>
            {renderMe}
        </div>
    )
```

renderData maps all users in the database and renderUser maps on user based on a search user name.  How can I build a switch statement or add to this conditional statement in order to handle a failed search case or return a default landing page when this.props.name === 'blank' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
    {this.props.view &&
      renderData //this will happen if this.props.view is truthy
    }
</div>
```

In React the && operator tells the following JSX to render only if the previous statement is true. That is usually the best solution if you want to either render something or not. However, in your case, where you want to basically toggle between two views, you probably want the ternary operator:

```
<div>
    {this.props.view ? renderData : renderUser}
</div>
```

Which basically says:
`{this.props.view ? (do this if true) : (do this if false) }`

To add the third case, you might just do this:

```
return (
        <div>
            {this.props.view ? renderData : renderUser}
            {this.props.name === 'blank' &&
                Sorry, user not found.
            }
        </div>
    )
```